# Factory method to create singleton instance

Tags: java, multithreading

I have written below code in static factory method to return single instance of DefaultCache.

```
public static ICache getInstance() {
   if (cacheInstance == null) {
      synchronized (ICache.class) {
         if (cacheInstance == null) {
            cacheInstance = new DefaultCache();
         }
      }
   }
   return cacheInstance;
}
```

Do we really need 2nd null check for **cacheInstance** inside the synchronized block?

Comment: In addition to answers, have a look at c2.com/cgi/wiki?SingletonsAreEvil

Comment: You might want to read Wikipedia article about [Double-checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_checked_locking_pattern#Usage_in_Java)

Answer (score 6):

You need the second check as the value could have been set by another thread while you are trying to get the lock. In fact you don't have a safe view of this value until you are inside the synchronized block.  It could have been set by another thread any amount of time ago.

The simplest lazy singleton is to use an enum

```
public enum DefaultCache implements ICache {
     INSTANCE
}
```

I assume you are not doing this so you can change the implementation.

BTW: I suggest you only use stateless singletons where possible and use dependanecy injection for all stateful objects as much as possible.

Answer (score 4):

I would avoid the need for the contention check using a lazily initialized singleton:

```
public class Singleton {
    public static ICache getInstance() {
       return LazyCacheInitializer.INSTANCE;
    }

    private class LazyCacheInitializer {
       private static final ICache INSTANCE = new DefaultCache();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the advantage of this over using an `enum`?

Comment: @Peter Well, on disadvantage of enums is their serialization model. Enums only serialize their names, but not their state. If the singleton can have any kind of state, it would be lost. As such, enums with state cannot be sent over the net, or saved and recovered from disk. Not sure if it would be helpful to think about serializing the singleton cache in this particular case, but your question was about an advantage/disadvantages.

Comment: While agree with your point, you would have to change this code quite a bit to use a deserialized cache so I am not sure this is much better for that.

Comment: @Peter Probably, but that was not the question, neither it was yours. My point was, simply, that enums would have trouble with that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, otherwise more than two instances can be created. Assume you have more than one threads. The first test is done with races conditions, ie some threads see the variable as null concurrently and try to set the instance. Without the second check, each thread will create a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `cacheInstance` is static you should consider two possible initialization strategies:

- Lazy initilization: The singleton field is populated with an instance
  at the moment when it's first used (as in your example).
- (Standarad) initialization: The singleton field is populated with an 
  instance as soon as the class is loaded by the JVM.

So if you intend to use lazy initilization you should check for nullity, otherwise you will just return a null pointer.

Alternatively you could also initialize the field in a static block.

```
//class declaration
 static {   
  cacheInstance = new DefaultCache(); 
 }
```

or in the same line where you declare it

```
private static final DefaultCache cacheInstance = new DefaultCache();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the `enum` based implementation of the singleton pattern like Peter posted but keep in mind that all of your implementations are singletons **per class loader**.

You also have to keep an eye out for the `Cloneable` interface too.

Answer (score -1):

Have a private constructor to avoid all these checks.

```
class Singleton {
    private static final Singleton instance = new Singleton();

    private Singleton() {
    }

    public static final Singleton getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```